# Create multi thread in clojure

Tags: clojure, luminus

I have this code:

```
      (do 
               ;**[1]** 
        (.start (Thread. 
          (http/get "http://127.0.0.1:8001/cardiologista/api/auth/ms1"
                       {:query-params {:verify "my-hash"}}))
        )
            ;**[2]**
        (.start (Thread. 
               (let [session (:session request)]
                   (-> (redirect "/client/dashboard")
                       (assoc :session verifica))))
        )
      )
```

I want to make a get call (**[1]**) and I don't want to wait for the callback (I won't use the callback), however, I don't want to wait for the response from that call to redirect (**[2]**) the page, I tried to do it that way (using thread), but it didn't work right.

In short: I want to make a GET call **[1]** and after that call to call the redirect function **[2]**, but I cannot wait for the GET call to respond. (I don't know if this would solve using thread)

Comment: Do you really need 2 threads? Your "redirect" logic should probably run in the current thread, so no need to create a new thread for that. Also I'd probably use futures instead of threads.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the future and solved the problem. I didn't really know this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the friend said in the comments, I used future to solve the problem, the function was like this:

```
(do 
  (future 
    (http/get "http://127.0.0.1:8001/cardiologista/api/auth/ms1"
              {:query-params {:verify "my-hash"}}))
  (let [session (:session request)]
    (-> (redirect "/cliente/dashboard")
        (assoc :session verifica))))
```

Comment: Do you really just want to fire a GET request out and ignore the result?

Comment: @cfrick Yes, my case is that after the user logs in to a service (in the case of this code), I need to save that session in the other service for future communications between these two services.

Comment: I would **not** start up a `future` then ignore the result. That is a recipe for really awful debugging experiences. `future`s swallow all exceptions that happen in them until you dereference them (`@`). Note `(do (future (/ 1 0)) (println "No exception?"))`. If you're going to use this, be **100%** sure that an exception will never happen in that future.